# How can I import element to another React component?

Tags: reactjs, react-ref

I've got 2 components and want to get `Panel_Menu` element in another child component to do some stuff with it.

```
class Panel extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.menuRef = React.createRef();  
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log (this.menuRef.current)
        // works correctly
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <>
                <Panel_Menu className="panel-menu" ref={this.menuRef}>
                    <Menu item={this.menuRef.current}/>
                </Panel_Menu>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

```
class Menu extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    isSame = () => {
        const isSlideClass = this.props.item;
        console.log(isSlideClass)
        // is null
        // expected output: → <div class="panel-menu"></div>
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Left_Menu >
                <Panel_Menu_Items className="test" onClick={this.isSame} />
            </Left_Menu>
        );
    }
}
```

How can I update data in done `render()` to reach my goal?

Or... how can I get element instantly in external Component (Menu in this case) to do some stuff with it?

Comment: Question is unclear. Do you just need need to import `PANEL_MENU` in the other component and render it? What does "it's getting the element but console.logs on second click" mean? I see no `onClick` handlers in your code. "How can i update data in done render() to reach my goal?" This is anti-pattern in React, the `render` method is a pure function. What data are you trying to update? You mention *some* other file... please include all relevant code in your question.

Comment: I've done update to clear my code and problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that React refs, when attached on the initial render, will be undefined *during* the initial render. This means that `item={this.menuRef.current}` will enclose the initial undefined ref value in the click handler of the child.

## Solution

It's simple, you really just need to trigger a rerender to reenclose an updated React ref value. You can either add some state to the `Panel` component and update it in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method, or just issue a forced update.

```
class Panel extends Component {
  menuRef = createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.menuRef.current);
    this.forceUpdate(); // <-- trigger rerender manually
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <PanelMenu className="panel-menu" ref={this.menuRef}>
          <Menu item={this.menuRef.current} />
        </PanelMenu>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit how-can-i-import-element-to-another-react-component]